# How do I get around "ValueError: not enough values to unpack"?

Tags: python, input, error-handling, multiple-input

I'm working on a program that works like so:

It asks for 2 inputs at once from the user, both of them are strings.
If 2 strings are given, it prints "Yes".
If only one string is given, it assumes the other one as "1" and prints "Maybe".
If nothing is given, it prints "No".

The problem is that it doesn't accept nothing for an answer.
If I type in only one string or nothing at all, it returns an error.

"ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1/0)"
How do I get around this?

Here is my code:

```
str1, str2 = input("Enter two values: ").split()
if str1 == "" and str2 == "":
    print("No")
elif str1 == str() and str2 == "":
    str2 = "1"
    print("Maybe")
else: print("Yes")
```

Comment: `str1, *str2 = input("Enter two values: ").split()`

Comment: @wwii `str1, *str2 = input("Enter two values: ").split()` Is this work?? if someone not input anything.

Comment: Not if they just hit ENTER.

Comment: Just assign to a single name and check it's length later. `str1 = input("Enter two values: ").split()`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note- This will work only if some input is given if someone hit the enter without input the error raises**

**Code:-**

```
str1, *str2 = input("Enter two values: ").split()
if str1 and str2:
    print("Yes")
elif str1 and str2==[]:
    str2="1"
    print("str2 Maybe: "+str2)
else:
    print("No")
```

**Output:-**

#Testcase1 **when str1 and str2 both input given**

```
Enter two values: 3 7
Yes
```

#Tescase2 **when str1 input given**

```
Enter two values: 5
str2 Maybe: 1
```

#Testcase3 **when no input given**

```
Enter two values: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected at least 1, got 0)
```

**To resolve this error ->**

```
(1)Try to take both inputs individually.
(2)Just assign to a single name and check it's length later. credit to ~wwii
```